# How to swap X-Server with Emacs org-mode?

Tags: xorg, bash, emacs, org-mode

I'm quite impressed of emacs' org-mode. So I want to use it for note-taking during lectures. To use it "distraction-free" my idea is the following:

I want to register a bash-command, which swaps the x-server session with `tty2` and starts emacs with its org-mode. Is it possible to pass my credentials from the x-server session to `tty2` (optional)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default tty2 is occupied by `init` for `getty`. You can probably change this by removing `/etc/init/tty2.conf`, but that was too adventurous for me and the instructions here are for tty9 instead (which is by default unallocated).

First, put these commands to `${HOME}/bin/orgmode.sh` or other file:

```
#!/bin/bash

TTY=/dev/tty9
USER=pschmidt

/usr/bin/sudo chown ${USER}.tty ${TTY}
/usr/bin/sudo chmod 620 ${TTY}
( /usr/bin/sudo -u ${USER} /usr/bin/emacs -t ${TTY} -nw ) &
/usr/bin/sudo chvt 9
```

(Use a different value for `USER` as necessary.)

Then, execute this bash command (not sure what you meant by register):

```
sudo time getty -n -l "${HOME}/bin/orgmode.sh" tty9 230400
```

Some caveats:

- The `time` command (or a similar dummy) is needed to prevent `sudo` terminal rearrangements from placing `emacs` on your current terminal
- The speed value of `230400` is there only because `getty` requires it, other values probably work also
- If `sudo` needs to ask your password and that messes up things, you can first run `sudo echo` and then the above command.